# what is the Mathematical principle of the tangle

Tags: tangle, double-spending

[image]

how do i  get the probability of the  douple-spending?

Comment: i don't know where does the "exp"  come from?

Comment: Why is the probability of success equal 1-exp(...)?

Comment: that is the [Cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)

Comment: `exp(x)` is another form of writing e^x

Comment: @mihi Thank you very much for your help, this has helped me a lot.But I have a new problem, t0 is the time interval, not the probability distribution function λ